# Why are "bug report" questions considered offtopic only at Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic, bug-reports, askubuntu

Why isn't there a same rule for Stackoverflow, Serverfault, Superuser, Unix & Linux and etc.?

Maybe one of the answers is that "Because Ubuntu has public bugtracker and/or is open source". In that case why not to prohibit "bug report" questions on other sites about software which has "public bugtracker and/or is open source"?

As for me, I'm against considering "bug report" questions offtopic and I'm aware of current prevaling community's point of view about that. But what's so special about Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: Why not ask about this on Meta.AskUbuntu.com? That's where such issues are discussed, not here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because my question isn't only about Ask Ubuntu

Comment: @janot yes it is. Voting to close.

Comment: They are off topic on Super User

Comment: @janot: each individual community sets the rules about what is on- and off-topic. Even if multiple communities happen to reach the same rules, that still makes discussion of any such rules *specific to each community*.

Comment: @janot: as such, this question pertains to *just* Ask Ubuntu, it is the community *there* that you need to ask this question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, I was wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the meaning of the rule.

> ## Questions that you should avoid:
>
> - [Bug reports](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site) ([How do I submit a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)).

This rule talks about bug reports for Ubuntu. The [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag on Meta sites is for reporting bugs in the Stack Exchange software.

As for why Ask Ubuntu has this rule/guideline, it's probably because they received many bug reports posted as questions. They're equally off-topic on the sites you mention, but such posts don't occur often enough to warrant a mention in the rules.